# How can I configure Analytics Engine use Hive LLAP using the Ambari UI?

Tags: hadoop, hive, ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

Is Hive LLAP feature supported by IAE?  If yes, how to enable it using the Ambari UI?

I tried to enable based on a [tutorial from Hortonworks](https://youtu.be/yQWV_wZYNEk) but I am getting errors:

```
$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.6.5.0-292/0/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1528895103783_0002 to YARN : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Queue root.default already has 1 applications, cannot accept submission of application: application_1528895103783_0002
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1528895103783_0002 to YARN : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Queue root.default already has 1 applications, cannot accept submission of application: application_1528895103783_0002
    at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.start(TezClient.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:579)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1528895103783_0002 to YARN : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Queue root.default already has 1 applications, cannot accept submission of application: application_1528895103783_0002
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.submitApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.tez.client.TezYarnClient.submitApplication(TezYarnClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.start(TezClient.java:383)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the procedure described in https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/interactive-sql-on-hadoop-with-hive-llap/, and it works.

I think, something that you should pay attention is about change the YARN memory as recommended, and one thing that is not in the procedure is to enable the "Pre-emption" YARN feature.

Regards,
Jean